# Using Recursion to Generate Possible Value Assignment Outcomes

Tags: algorithm, recursion, random

I'm trying to come up with a recursive algorithm to generate all possible child - parent assignment possibilities given complete randomness.

For example, say I have 3 children and 2 parents, all children will be randomly assigned to each parent with the following possible outcomes

```
   Parent 1       Parent 2

   0 Children     3 Children
   1 Children     2 Children
   2 Children     1 Children 
   3 Children     0 Children
```

I've been trying to wrap my head around a way to do this recursively supplying the number of children and number of parents along with other variables for keeping track of the current state but have been unable to find anything that works. It needs to work for any given number of parents and children.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm coding in Java although its not so much the code but the algorithm I need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have n children and k parents. Then the following algorithm (in pseudo-java) should work :

```
int[] childrensForParent = new int[k];

/**
* Method assigns numberOfChildren children to parents with indices from 
* parentIndex to k-1
*/
void assignChildren(int parentIndex, int numberOfChildren) {
    if(parentIndex==k-1) {
         //All children left go to the last parent in a row
         childrensForParent[parentIndex] = numberOfChildren;
         //Do something with the result
         output(childrensForParent);
         return;
    } 
    for(int childrenCount= 0; childrenCount<=numberOfChildren; childrenCount++) {
        //assign children to current parent
        childrensForParent[parentIndex] = childrenCount;
        //assign children that left to next parents
        assignChildren(parentIndex+1, numberOfChildren-childrenCount);
    }
}

//Method call
assignChildren(0,n);
```

Short explanatation:

1. If you have only one parent assign all of the children left
2. Otherwise if you have `k` parent and `n` children

   1. For each possible children count `x` (from 0 to `n`)

      1. Assign `x` children to the current parent
      2. Assign `n-x` children to the remaining (`k-1`) parents (recursion call).

**Additional information:**
The algorithm above generate all non-negative partitions of `n` into `k` parts. Check out these articles:

- [Partition on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts);
- [Question on Math.SE about the number of such partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers)

Answer (score 1):

This is all completely untested, but you could start with the following logic/pseudo code:

```
// Define your starting objects/data
define a parent object that has a list field of children
define "parents" as an array of parent objects
define "children" as an array of children objects

// Prepare the data
randomize the "children" array via a shuffling algorithm

// Define your recursive method
define recursiveAssignChildren(parents, children):
    if children is empty, exit method
    take the first element of "children" and assign it to a random parent
    define lessChildren as children, excluding the first element that was already assigned to a parent
    call recursiveAssignChildren(parents, lessChildren)

// Call the recursive method to start process
call recursiveAssignChildren(parents, children)
```

Comment: This looks like a nice way to create a random partition (shuffle children). But it doesn't seem to generate all possible outcomes.

Comment: Oops, seems like a misread the question!  You are right, this algorithm only generates a single outcome, not all possible outcomes.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what OP has in mind. Maybe your answer will suit his/her needs.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems are wearing a cover made by the problem setter. This can be achieved by making the problem as someone is telling you a riddle (long sentences, less information) . So, to uncover this problem you think like this: instead of dealing with this problem as children need to be assigned to parents in all possible ways, you have two numbers n1, n2 (number of children number of parents respectively) and you want to add n1 using n2 additions so if you have  3 children needs to be assigned to 2 parents here you want to to form 3 using 2 addition operations

```
   void generateAll(int c, int p, string str)
{
    if (c == 0 && p == 0)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
        return;
    }
    // if there are no parents and c > 0 then no children going to be asigned to any parent
    if (p == 0 && c > 0)
        return;
    // loop throug number of children 
    for (int i = 0; i <= c; i++)
    {
        generateAll(c - i, p - 1, str + "\t"+ toString(i));
    }
}
```